# QGIS lacks libjvm.so on Ubuntu Precise

Tags: gis, java, java-7, ubuntu-12.04, qgis

I installed QGIS via [ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable?field.series_filter=precise). My Ubuntu 12.04 comes with OpenJDK 1.7.0. When I start qgis from the command line the following error message is returned.

> /usr/bin/qgis.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Since I expected a dependency for Oracle Java [I installed JDK 1.7.0 following these instructions](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/). The error message, however, is still there.

Though, the file can be found on the harddisc three times (no symlinks).

```
$ locate libjvm.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/cacao/libjvm.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jamvm/libjvm.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
```

What do you recommend doing to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your packages.  The `libgdal1-1.9.0-2ppa4` package had a fluke dependency on `libjvm.so` which wasn't supposed to be there.  I'm not having any issues with the `libgdal1-1.9.1-2~precise3` version from the ubuntugis-unstable PPA.

Comment: I would like to install the latest packages or remove the former before. However, apt-get fails to remove them: http://pastebin.com/Zv2Siu5j Do you have any advice?

Comment: Thank you so much. Was tearing my hair out because this was breaking postgis.